# MySql как продиагностировать какая из баз данных сильнее всего грузит сервер?

Tags: mysql, centos

На сервере 4 хоста и 4 БД соответственно. Вывод команды htop показывает много запущенных процессов mysql которые съедают почти всю ОП.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли как то узнать какая из этих БД и как по какой причине съедает ОП, в общем как диагностировать проблему в таких случаях? Опыта работы с подобным мало, буду рад любым советам.

Конфиг БД

```
#
# Basic mysql configuration. Use bvat for advanced settings.
# Parameters set by bvat are stored in /etc/mysql/conf.d/bvat.cnf.
# If you want to change any parameter, you'll have to redefine it in /etc/mysql/conf.d/z_bx_custom.cnf
#

[client]
port = 3306
socket = /var/lib/mysqld/mysqld.sock
default-character-set = utf8

[mysqld_safe]
nice = 0
socket = /var/lib/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]

# Basic mysql server configuration
user = mysql
#bind-address = "49.12.165.244"
port = 3306
basedir = /usr
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
socket = /var/lib/mysqld/mysqld.sock
skip-external-locking
default-storage-engine = innodb
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED
max_allowed_packet = 32M
myisam-recover-options = BACKUP
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 1
expire_logs_days = 10
max_binlog_size = 100M
sql_mode = ""

# Cache parameters
query_cache_size = 32M
table_open_cache = 4096
thread_cache_size = 32
key_buffer_size = 16M
thread_stack = 128K
join_buffer_size = 2M
sort_buffer_size = 2M

# Parameters for temporary tables
tmpdir = /tmp
max_heap_table_size = 32M
tmp_table_size = 32M

# InnoDB parameters
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 32M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_log_file_size = 64M
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
# innodb_force_recovery = 1

# Database charset parameters
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect = "SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci"
#skip-character-set-client-handshake
skip-name-resolve

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet = 32M
default-character-set = utf8

[mysql]

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 16M

# Include additional settings
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Еще дополнительный кофиг который инклюдится

```
[mysqld]
    query_cache_type = 1
    query_cache_size = 128M
    query_cache_limit = 16M
    innodb_buffer_pool_size = 18432M
    max_connections = 205
    table_open_cache = 18432
    thread_cache_size = 512
    max_heap_table_size = 128M
    tmp_table_size = 128M
    key_buffer_size = 256M
    join_buffer_size = 32M
    sort_buffer_size = 32M
    bulk_insert_buffer_size = 2M
    myisam_sort_buffer_size = 32M
```

Comment: Никто ничего не грузит, просто вы разрешили использовать память под кэширование в настройках mysql, вот он и кэширует. Хотите чтобы кушало меньше — уменьшайте innodb_buffer_pool_size и подобные настройки

Comment: И это не процессы, а потоки

Comment: Благодарю за пояснение про потоки. Запомню. Был такой момент что сервер одного из сайтов упал с 502 ошибкой, увеличили ОП, пока все хорошо. 

Конфиг БД прикрепил в главном сообщение

Comment: Дополнил снова, еще один кофиг

Comment: `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 18432M` ну вот и причина потребления памяти собственно

Comment: Простите за нубский вопрос, получается что innodb_buffer_pool_size примерно равен 18 гб, на сервере доступно 40 гб, почему в htop показывает 24,2 ?

Вроде как рекомендуют устанавливать innodb_buffer_pool_size  70-80% от общедоступной ОП.

Comment: Во-первых, не 24.2, а 21.7 (вы не тот столбик смотрите), во-вторых, разумеется есть ещё всякие разные другие буферы которые тоже кушают память, но на фоне innodb_buffer_pool_size всё остальное кушает немного

Comment: Благодарю за ответы, сейчас уменьшу на несколько гигов innodb_buffer_pool_size.